# form effect - smoothly highlight even when you move the mouse away

Tags: jquery, css

hi someone know how to make this form effect: [http://www.clouddigitalmedia.co.uk/contact-us](http://www.clouddigitalmedia.co.uk/contact-us.html) When you click the form field, it will smoothly highlight even when you move the mouse away from the field, unless you hit the click button outside the box.

I'm not sure if this is a CSS3 thing, or maybe there is a jQuery for this.

Comment: I believe they're using CSS3 transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the pseudo-class of `:focus`. This basically says that if the mouse has the text blinker inside of it, then apply the styles. Here is an example

```
input{
 /*Transition Properties*/
}
input:focus{
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dZ4Jh/2/